# Symfony3 imag ldap set up configuration

Tags: php, ldap, symfony

Writting a Symfony3 app and need to connect to a AD via LDAP to log a user in. I did some googling around and found this: [ldap setup](https://packagist.org/packages/imag/ldap-bundle) so I have followed this doc through but get this error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "security.firewall.map.context.restricted_area" has a dependency on a non-existent service "security.context".
in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58

at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Reference), object(Reference), object(Reference), object(Definition), 'restricted_area', object(Definition), object(Definition), array('check_path' => '/login_check', 'use_forward' => false, 'require_previous_session' => true, 'username_parameter' => '_username', 'password_parameter' => '_password', 'csrf_parameter' => '_csrf_token', 'intention' => 'ldap_authenticate', 'post_only' => true), object(Reference), object(Reference))) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 42
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 53
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition))) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 51
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processReferences(array(array(object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition), object(Definition)), object(Definition))) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 42
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processDefinition(object(Definition)) in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 36
at CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 104
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 545
at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 477
at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 166
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
```

security.yml:

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    firewalls:
      restricted_area:
        pattern:          ^/
        anonymous:        ~
        provider:         ldap
        imag_ldap:        ~
            # alternative configuration
            # imag_ldap:
            #   login_path:   /ninja/login
        logout:
          path:           /logout
          target:         /

    providers:
      chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, ldap]
      fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
      ldap:
        id: imag_ldap.security.user.provider

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
        IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

imag_ldap:
  client:
    host: someip
    port: 389
        #    version: 3 # Optional
        #    username: foo # Optional
        #    password: bar # Optional
        #    network_timeout: 10 # Optional
        #    referrals_enabled: true # Optional
        #    bind_username_before: true # Optional
        #    skip_roles: false # Optional

  user:
    base_dn: ou=group, dc=host, dc=foo
        #    filter: (&(foo=bar)(ObjectClass=Person)) #Optional
    name_attribute: uid
  role:
    base_dn: ou=group, dc=host, dc=foo
        #    filter: (ou=group) #Optional
    name_attribute: cn
    user_attribute: member
#    user_id: [ dn || username ]

    #  user_class: IMAG\LdapBundle\User\LdapUser # Optional
```

From what i understand the secyrity.yml has a dependency on context but in the ldap set up docs nothing is mentioned about it...?

maybe am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [BorisMorel / LdapBundle](https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle) works with Symfony3; it hasn't been updated in years...

I highly suggest you use [Maks3w / FR3DLdapBundle](https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle), since the maintainer often checks Stackoverflow for questions. There is a tag for [fr3dldapbundle on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fr3dldapbundle) for posting questions.